# How to route to different apps on cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have added my domain to route 53 and routed it to a cloudfront distribution and I also have a lambda function with an api gateway on top of it (/api)

How can I handle routing with route 53 (or cloudfront) to do something like this

Test.com/* > cloudfront > s3

Test.com/api/* > api gateway > lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 2 different cache behaviors in CloudFront and point them to the different origins:

1. Create one behavior for `/api` with `API Gateway` as origin
2. Create another default behavior with `S3` as origin

Comment: yeap it was easier than expected :) do you know if I can use a regex to route to lamba vs s3? like /test route it to S3 and /test.jpg route it to api gateway?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that. The scenario here https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-route-to-multiple-origins-with-cloudfront/ seems very similar to yours

Answer (score 1):

Route53 is just a DNS service. You want to proxy traffic based on their routes. This is known as path-based routing. Application Load Balancers afford this functionality via Listener Rules. See the following documents to learn more:

- [Introduction to Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html)
- [Listeners for your Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html)